# value of NULL after inserting value

Tags: r, data.table

I use the following code:

```
library(data.table)
SRC2 <- read.table(header=TRUE, text='"sequenceID" "transactionID" "eventID" "items"  "Exist" 
"1" 42207993       1577          1        "OV50"     1     
"2" 42207993       6048          2        "OV11"     0     
"3" 42207993       1597          3        "OV148"    1     
"4" 57237976       12423         1        "OV46"     0     
"5" 57237976       12589         2        "OV197"    1')

setDT(SRC2)
SRC2$Exist<- as.integer(SRC2$Exist)

i1 <- SRC2[, Co:= as.character(round(sum(Exist)/.N, 2)) , sequenceID][, .I[1:(.N-1)], sequenceID]$v1
```

When I try to find the content of i1:

```
> i1
NULL
```

Why do I get the value `NULL` instead of the required value: `1 2 4`? How can I get the required values?

Finally I would like to use the following command:

```
 SRC2[i1, Co:= '']
```

And because i1 is NULL I get the following:

```
> SRC2[i1, Co:= '']
Null data.table (0 rows and 0 cols)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote `v1` instead of `V1`.

So this works:

```
i1 <- SRC2[, Co:= as.character(round(sum(Exist)/.N, 2)) ,
           sequenceID][, .I[1:(.N-1)], sequenceID]$V1
```